# How to make one action that handles and renders different pages

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is it possible in zf2 that i only have one controller and one action that i can reuse for different pages?

Say.

```
   Class SiteController extends AbstractActionController{


    public function viewAction(){

       // use for the homepage, product, category etc pages.


    }


    }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible playing with route and parameters, but your controller may become hard to read and maintain. In your action method you will have to explicitly return ViewModel instance with your desired template tree, if you don't Zf2 will try to render a view with the name of your action (for ex: `application/site/view`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could use a parameter to load different content.

Class SiteController extends AbstractActionController{

```
    public function viewAction(){
       $content = $this->params()->fromRoute('slug');

       // Query or logic using slug to load different content dynamically

    }
}
```

module.config.php

```
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                    'site' => array(
                            'type'    => 'literal',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/site',
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\SiteControllerr',
                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                    ),
                            ),
                            'may_terminate' => true,
                            'child_routes' => array(
                                'view' => array(
                                    'type' => 'segment',
                                    'options' => array(
                                        'route' => '/[:slug]',
                                        'constraints' => array(
                                            'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
                                        ),
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                            'action' => 'view'
                                        )
                                    )
                                ),
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
    ),
```

Now you can have routes like

/site/products
/site/categories

Answer (score 1):

I worked with ZF2 for a bit with PimCore, and I came to the same problem, each controller was specific to a certain view, I figured out by looking at the Zend_View class for a while that I could create a 'loadView' method to work around this:

```
/**
     * Load and render an arbitrary view.
     * Path is set to the ./website/views/scripts/
     * @param string $name name / path of the view relative to ./website/views/scripts/ (No leading /)
     * @param array $params key => value assoc array of variables to be passed to the view.
     * @return string rendered view string.
     */
    protected function loadView($name, $params=array()) {
        $view = new Zend_View(array('scriptPath' => './website/views/scripts/'));

        if(is_object($params))
            $params = (array)$params;

        foreach($params as $key => $value)
            $view->assign($key, $value);

        return $view->render($name);
    }
```

That may work for you too.

EDIT**
Ofcourse you may need to change the basepath to your view files... :)

Comment: PimCore is more likely using ZF1 and not ZF2 which are different...(MVC to MOVE pattern)